# V-model populated in a method not updating the DOM

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am newbie in VueJs.(vue 2). I have a problem here. I have a table where I am dynamically populating data like this.

```
<tbody>
      <tr v-bind:key="queProduct.value" v-for="queProduct in queueProducts">
        <td class="has-text-centered">
                        <figure class="image is-48x48">
            <img :src="queProduct.image" alt="Placeholder image">
                        </figure>
        </td>
        <td><span>{{queProduct.title}}</span></td>
        <td class="has-text-centered"><a class="has-text-link">
          <span class="icon is-size-4" @click="openModalPopup(queProduct.id)">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit" />
          </span>
        </a>
        </td>
                     <td class="has-text-centered"><a class="has-text-link">
          <span class="icon is-size-4" @click="openModalPopup(queProduct.id)">
            <img :src="queProduct.indicatorImg" />
          </span>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td class="has-text-centered"><a class="delete is-large has-background-link" @click="removeFromQueue(queProduct.id)"></a></td>
      </tr>
            </tbody>
```

```js
methods:{
  loadQueue(){

    const indicators = store.get('productIndicators');
    if(indicators === undefined){
      store.set('productIndicators', []);
    } else {
      this.savedProprogressIndicators = indicators;
    }
    this.queueProducts.forEach(product => {
      product.indicatorImg = indicatorImgBaseUrl +'Level-0.png';
      this.savedProprogressIndicators.forEach(indicator => {
        if(indicator.id === product.id){
          product.indicatorImg = indicatorImgBaseUrl +indicator.image;
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

When I console.log the product, I see the product object being updated with the new value. But the dom isnt getting updated. Like,

this.product looks like this.

```
{
  id: "d6dd8228-e0a6-4cb7-ab83-50ca5a937d45"
  image: "https://zuomod.ca/image/cache/catalog/products/2018/Single/medium/50105-1-800x800.jpg"
  inQueue: false
  indicatorImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0003/9252/7936/files/Level-2.png"
  saved: false
  sku: "50105"
  title: "Interstellar Ceiling Lamp"
}
```

But in the DOM, it looks like this

```
{
  id: "d6dd8228-e0a6-4cb7-ab83-50ca5a937d45"
  image: "https://zuomod.ca/image/cache/catalog/products/2018/Single/medium/50105-1-800x800.jpg"
  inQueue: false
  indicatorImg: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0003/9252/7936/files/Level-0.png"
  saved: false
  sku: "50105"
  title: "Interstellar Ceiling Lamp"
}
```

Can you please help me resolve this?

Thanks,
Vandanaa

Comment: Could you provide the code that return queueProducts ?

Comment: I have queueProducts declared under data like this ` data() {
    return {
           
            queueProducts:[]
    }
    }` and populating in load function like this ` this.queueProducts = store.get('queueProducts');`

Comment: Hi Vandanaa. Am I right in thinking that you are using Vuex in your project too, or is the call to 'store' purely coincidental? Just wanted to clarify that before proceeding.

Comment: I think is it, store are related to vues

Comment: yes, I am using an electron store since its an vue-electron application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use Vuex, you should get your products directly from you store like in computed property in your vue definition. This will refresh the data directly from store without any action from vue side.

```
{
...
computed:{
   ...mapGetters({
     queueProducts : 'queueProducts'
   })
}
...
}
```

Furthermore, if your are using vuex, try to keep your logic inside your store. You vue should only display data.

Hava a look to vuex documentation to know when and where you should use 
**Getters, Mutations and Actions**.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.queueProducts.forEach(product => {
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
this.$forceUpdate(); // Trying to add this code
```

I guessed your product.indicatorImg was not been watch by Vue, so it will not update the DOM. Trying to add `this.$forceUpdate()` in the end. It will force Vue to update DOM.